# Estimating Exponential Decay Rate and its confidence interval from Beta Regression Odds Ratio fit

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, beta-regression, glmmtmb

I am working with a random variable that is bounded between 0 and 1, and its mean decreases exponentially over time. I am seeking to estimate this exponential decay rate with its corresponding confidence interval.

Beta regression models with link logit estimate the change in log odds as time increases by one unit. However, this interpretation differs from the rate at which the mean of the random variable decreases over time.

I have developed a script that successfully estimates the exponential decay rate and the mean probability at time zero using the coefficients obtained from the Beta regression. However, I could not estimate the corresponding confidence interval.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights you may have regarding methods or techniques to obtain these estimations, particularly in terms of calculating the confidence interval.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(glmmTMB)
  library(gamlss)

  set.seed(1)
# Define parameters
  N <- 100
  X <- rep(0:5, each = N)
  RESULT <- NULL

# Loop through different values of INT and RATE
for (INT in c(0.95, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1)) {
  for (RATE in c(0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3)) {
    # Calculate MEAN
    MEAN <- INT * RATE^X
    
    # Generate data frame
    DF <- data.frame(X = X, Y = rBE(N * 6, mu = MEAN, sigma = 0.2))
    
    # Fit glmmTMB model
    MOD <- glmmTMB(Y ~ X, family = beta_family(link = "logit"), data = DF)
    
    # Obtain predicted values
    PRED <- as.data.frame(ggpredict(MOD, terms = ~X))
    
    # Create a data frame with results
    RESULT_ROW <- data.frame(INT = INT, RATE = RATE, INT.MOD = PRED[1, 2], 
                             ODDS = exp(summary(MOD)$coefficients$cond[2, 1]))
    
    # Append the row to the RESULT data frame
    RESULT <- rbind(RESULT, RESULT_ROW)
  }
}

  RESULT # Print the result

# Estimating Exponential decaing from Odds ration and Intercept
  LM1 <- lm(RATE ~ poly(ODDS, 2) * INT.MOD, data = RESULT)
  summary(LM1)
  ggplot(RESULT, aes(x = ODDS, y = RATE, color = factor(INT))) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), se = FALSE) +
    theme_classic()

# Estimating mean probability at time zero from Odds ration and Intercept
  LM2 <- lm(INT ~ poly(INT.MOD, 2) * RATE, data = RESULT)
  summary(LM2)
  ggplot(RESULT, aes(x = INT.MOD, y = INT, color = factor(RATE))) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = 2) +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), se = FALSE) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the packages you're using, but I know that `brms` is capable of implementing non-linear models. See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_nonlinear.html) for a detailed explanation of the syntax and other considerations.

If I understood your model correctly, this is how I would implement it:

```r
library(brms)
library(gamlss)
init <- 0.75
rate <- 0.66
mu <- init*(rate**(0:5))
data <- data.frame(x = 0:5, y = rBE(60, mu, 0.2))

formula <- bf(y ~ init*rate**x, init + rate ~ 1,
              family = Beta(link = "identity"), nl = TRUE)

prior_df <- get_prior(formula, data)
prior_df[3, 1] <- "normal(0.5, 2)"
prior_df[5, 1] <- "normal(0.5, 2)"

fit <- brm(formula, data, prior = prior_df,
           backend = "cmdstanr")

fit
#>  Family: beta 
#>   Links: mu = identity; phi = identity 
#> Formula: y ~ init * rate^x 
#>          init ~ 1
#>          rate ~ 1
#>    Data: data (Number of observations: 60) 
#>   Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
#>          total post-warmup draws = 4000
#> 
#> Population-Level Effects: 
#>                Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> init_Intercept     0.73      0.02     0.68     0.77 1.00     2549     2669
#> rate_Intercept     0.68      0.01     0.65     0.71 1.00     2510     2618
#> 
#> Family Specific Parameters: 
#>     Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> phi    26.72      4.90    18.03    36.89 1.00     2437     2549
#> 
#> Draws were sampled using sample(hmc). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
#> and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
#> scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The `phi` parameter shown in the summary is related to the `sigma` from `gamlss::rBE` as $\sigma = \phi^{-1/2}$. So as you can see, all the parameters are recovered quite effectively.

To be clear, this library uses Bayesian inference, hence the need to set priors. The choice I made here was just based on intuition, so you may want to be more careful there for your particular application.

Also note that the CIs are credible intervals rather than frequentist confidence intervals, but you might be able to ignore the difference for practical purposes when you have enough data (see the [Bernstein–von Mises theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem)).